# Can we const-cast a non-class prvalue to xvalue?

Tags: c++, casting, language-lawyer, temporary, const-cast

Consider this example from 7.6.1.10, paragraph 3 [expr.const.cast] ([N4810](http://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG21/docs/papers/2019/n4810.pdf)):

```
typedef int *A[3]; // array of 3 pointer to int
typedef const int *const CA[3]; // array of 3 const pointer to const int
...
A &&r2 = const_cast<A&&>(CA{}); // OK
```

So, **the standard says** it's a legitimate code, but

- none of `g++-7` or `clang-6` compiles fine.
- In fact, [this `const_cast`-related comments](http://llvm.org/viewvc/llvm-project/cfe/trunk/lib/Sema/SemaCast.cpp?r1=183394&r2=184017&pathrev=184017) from `llvm` states:

  ```
  ....

  if (isa<RValueReferenceType>(DestTypeTmp) && SrcExpr.get()->isRValue()) {
      if (!SrcType->isRecordType()) {
          // Cannot const_cast non-class prvalue to rvalue reference type. But if
          // this is C-style, static_cast can do this.
          msg = diag::err_bad_cxx_cast_rvalue;
          return TC_NotApplicable;
      }

      // Materialize the class prvalue so that the const_cast can bind a
      // reference to it.
      NeedToMaterializeTemporary = true;
  }

  ...
  ```

  This basically says that we can't *materialize*(=cast) **a non-class *prvalue*** to a *xvalue*.
- Also, the same paragraph from which the above example originates says:

  > For two similar types `T1` and `T2`, a prvalue of type `T1` may be
  >   explicitly converted to the type `T2` using a `const_cast`. The result of
  >   a `const_cast` refers to **the original entity**.

  Compare this to the one right after it (7.6.1.10, paragraph 4 [expr.const.cast]):

  > For two object types `T1` and `T2`, if a pointer to `T1` can be
  >   explicitly converted to the type “pointer to `T2`” using a
  >   `const_cast`, then the following conversions can also be made:
  >
  > - an *lvalue* of type `T1` can be explicitly converted to an *lvalue* of type `T2` using the cast `const_cast<T2&>`;
  > - a *glvalue* of type `T1` can be explicitly converted to an *xvalue* of type `T2` using the cast `const_cast<T2&&>`;
  >     and
  > - **if `T1` is a class type**, a *prvalue* of type `T1` can be explicitly converted to an *xvalue* of type `T2` using the cast `const_cast<T2&&>`.
  >
  > The result of a reference const_cast refers to the original object if the operand is a glvalue and **to the result of applying the temporary materialization conversion otherwise**.

  This contrast seems to insinuate that, a cast from a non-class *prvalue* to a *xvalue* **won't suffer** temporary materialization conversion, which looks odd to me.

Then, what's the intention of the example above?

Comment: http://wg21.link/cwg1965

Comment: _The result of a `const_cast` refers to the original entity_ This wording is clearly defective, because in C++17 and above prvalues do not denote entities.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer So, the above example is defective. Thanks.

Comment: @LanguageLawyer The wording is not defective. The wording you quoted is in paragraph 3, and doesn't apply to the reference case, which is paragraph 4. The wording in paragraph 4 makes it clear that the result only refers to the original object if the operand is a glvalue.

Comment: @Brian the first and the second sentence in paragraph 3 are not related?

Comment: @LanguageLawyer They are. The second sentence in paragraph 3 is related to the first sentence in paragraph 3. Paragraph 3 does not apply to the case where the destination type is a reference, because a reference type can never be similar to the non-reference type of the operand.

Comment: @Brian _Paragraph 3 does not apply to the case where the destination type is a reference_ But I didn't mean this. I just told that in C++17 and above prvalues can't denote objects, so one can't "refer to the original entity".

Comment: @LanguageLawyer Ah, I see what you mean now. I suppose the wording does need improvement. I think it was meant to denote cases like casting `const int*` to `int*`, where the resulting value *points* to the same entity as the original value.

Comment: @Brian Although, [basic.lval]/2 says _A prvalue whose result is the value V is sometimes said to have or name the value V_, so it can be said that a prvalue denotes entity (value).